# What is the fastest and pythonic way to generate a list [(0,0), (0,1), (0,2)...(0,100)]?

Tags: python, performance, loops, iteration

**What is the fastest and pythonic way to generate a list [(0,0), (0,1), (0,2)...(0,100)]?**

I know there is a statement like `l = [(0, x) for x in range(101)]` but it has a for loop, so I don't think that is the fastest way to make a list like this.

So what would be the most pythonic way to make this kind of list?

Comment: list comprehension is the most pythonic way

Comment: I think your code is pythonic enough.

Comment: Using a generator instead should be faster. (It does nothing until it gets used. If you don't use it, it's therefore "fastest".)

Comment: Why do you think a for loop is slow?

Comment: It's not a `for` loop; list comprehensions just share the `for` keyword with `for` loops.

Comment: Thank you it helped a lot. I think I don't have to struggle with my code unless it does not make any performance problem.

Comment: `list(zip(itertools.repeat(0), range(101)))` might be a hair faster, but certainly less readable.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a faster solution you can use [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

```
from itertools import repeat:

list(zip(repeat(0), range(101)))
```

benchmark:

```
%timeit [(0, x) for x in range(101)]
# 3.64 µs ± 19.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit list(zip(repeat(0), range(101)))
# 2.81 µs ± 35.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Another Pythonic solution:

```
list((0, x) for x in range(101))
```

Comment: It is faster but the pythonic way is more readable. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: `repeat(0)` is sufficient, without having to repeat the length. `zip` stops iterating after its shortest argument (in this case, `range(101)`) is exhausted.

Comment: @chepner thx for adviece

Comment: There's little reason to consider `list` + a generator expression over a list comprehension. It's no more readable, and it's slower.

Comment: a very small difference I would say btw list comprehension and  list + generator expression and is more readable to use `list` + a generator expression, but this may be debatable

Comment: @kederrac: Throwing away all comprehensions in favor of generator expressions is no more readable. By that logic, all literal syntax for collections should be replaced with constructor + `tuple` literal (or whichever literal you think is most obvious) or the like. Side-note: Probably ever-so-slightly faster would be `[*zip(repeat(0), range(101))]` as it avoids general function calls in favor of interpreter supported syntax. Not recommending it, just mentioning that if you're really hard up for cycles for some reason, it's (usually) faster.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I didn't say to throw away all comprehension, I just give to OP an option, sure the list comprehension is just fine

Comment: @kederrac: The objection is to introducing `list((0, x) for x in range(101))` as "a pythonic solution" (which implies both prior solutions are unpythonic). "Another Pythonic solution" would avoid the issue; I consider it less Pythonic than the listcomp, but it's not *bad* style.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, sure "Another Pythonic solution" is better, thx

Answer (score 2):

**If you haven't done profiling to prove the performance is a problem, then the solution should be the listcomp you already mentioned:**

```
l = [(0, x) for x in range(101)]
```

**It's readable and it's fast enough** (takes 3-4 μs on most machines, which means you could do it over a quarter million times per second), **so don't bother looking for faster solutions unless you really need it.**

If profiling does somehow show this is the hottest code, and it's actually causing bottlenecks affecting performance, you could go with micro-optimized nonsense like:

```
from itertools import repeat, count  # At top of file

l = [*zip(repeat(0, 101), count())]  # At point of use
```

which runs in roughly ⅔ the time of the listcomp. But that's a half-measure at best. **If you know you need to generate this precise `list` many times, and performance *really* matters, the solution is to stop *generating* the `list` at all. Use a readable listcomp to make a template, than copy that template on demand:**

```
TEMPLATE_LIST = [(0, x) for x in range(101)]  # At top of file (global scope)

l = [*TEMPLATE_LIST]  # Slightly faster on 3.8.0, but generalized unpacking less widely known
l = TEMPLATE_LIST[:]  # Slightly slower, but shallow copy idiom well-known
```

or if you want some protection against in-place modifications to the template `list`:

```
MAKE_TEMPLATE_LIST = [(0, x) for x in range(101)].copy  # At top of file (global scope)

l = MAKE_TEMPLATE_LIST()  # At point of use
```

A cheap shallow copy of a template `list` is *much* faster, and conveniently, all your values are immutable (`tuple`s of `int`s), so you don't need a more expensive deep copy. That runs in less than 10% of the time required by even the micro-optimized nonsense solution (~220-230 ns for `TEMPLATE_LIST[:]` on my machine, ~190-200 ns for both `[*TEMPLATE_LIST]` and `MAKE_TEMPLATE_LIST()`), and all parts of it are obvious (`MAKE_TEMPLATE_LIST` is less obvious). The main weaknesses are:

1. The definition of the `TEMPLATE_LIST` is separated from where it's used, so maintainers have to cross-reference (some IDEs will help with hover tips at least)
2. `TEMPLATE_LIST` is subject to modification; `MAKE_TEMPLATE_LIST` is harder to modify by accident, but could still be replaced. In either case, that's a matter of code discipline, not something to fight ("We're all adults here")
3. Permanent memory use (not relevant with a `list` this small; if you're hard up for the 6 KB of memory this costs, maybe Python is the wrong language for you)

**TL;DR**: Use the listcomp unless you're 100% sure you need the speed. If you're sure, copying an existing `list` is going to be faster than rebuilding it from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I won't bother looking for faster solutions unless I really need it.

Comment: And the TEMPLATE_LIST implementation's performance improvement were notable.